# compiling two C files using the terminal, one file includes a.h and two file include c.h

Tags: c, gcc, compilation

I'm trying to compile two C files using the terminal. File `one.c` includes `a.h` and file `two.c` includes `c.h` but I'm receiving the following errors

```
one.c fatal error: a.h No such file or directory
two.c fatal error: c.h No such file or directory
```

I think the issue is with the command I'm using to run gcc. What's the right command to compile these two files together?

`one.c` starts with

```
#include "a.h"
#include "b.h"
```

`two.c` starts with

```
#include "c.h"
#include "b.h"
```

Comment: It should be `#include "a.h"` with quotes - is that a typo?  Are the files `a.h` and `c.h` located in the same directory where you are running gcc?

Comment: When I use GCC 10.2.0, I get an error like: `one43.c:1:10: error: #include expects "FILENAME" or <FILENAME>` for `#include a.h`.  For `#include "c.h"`, I get: `one43.c:3:10: fatal error: c.h: No such file or directory`.  The information in the question is inaccurate.  We need to see an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) — or MRE or whatever name SO now uses). That will be a minimized version of `one.c`, the command line for compiling, the errors, and info on where the headers are stored. File `one.c` might be just two `#include` statements long.

Comment: That was a typo in the question, I fixed it now. the quotes are not my problem here

Answer (score 0):

Just add the quotes like this `#include "a.h"` and make sure that all the header files .h are located in your include path

Comment: As I noted in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65957203/compiling-two-c-files-using-the-terminal-one-file-includes-a-h-and-two-file-inc#comment116617578_65957203), the claimed error messages don't align with the claimed code.  If the code shown is accurate, you're right (but the error messages in the question are then probably wrong).  If the error messages are right, then the code is wrong and it isn't clear that your proposed solution is relevant.